# Separate() function in R not splitting according to chosen character delimiter

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have a 21 column dataframe of RNA transcript information on R studio and column 8 ("V8") has 21 rows each with a string of text in this format: Gbp4|AW228052|Mag-2|Mpa-2|Mpa2|-|5.

I'm trying to extract this information by delimiting using the "|" as a separator and creating separate columns for each section, however the resulting output only seems to spread the characters out into the new columns instead.

To perform the delimiting I've been using the tidyr separate() function calling sep="|" and extra="drop. I've also tried using strsplit

```
separate(data = IKDNprBIND.Down_4OHT_d1_vs_DMSO.txt, col = V8, into = c("GeneName","Annotations1","Annotations2","Annotations3","Annotations4),"Annotations5","Annotations6","Annotations7", sep = "|",extra = "drop")
```

Alternative

```
strsplit(as.character(IKDNprBIND.Down_4OHT_d1_vs_DMSO.txt$V8),'|')
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

[Code expectation][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cffrA.png

The output I got is as follows:

[Code output][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWLIn.png

As you can see the 'GeneName' columnn is blank and instead, the first character of the string is pasted into the second column and the rest of the characters are pasted into the following columns. It seems like instead of separating by "|" my code is separating by individual characters and I'm not sure why that is

Strsplit also doesnt separate the characters out and instead returns a 41 element list with each row string character like so:

[Strsplit output][3] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDjpR.png

I've tried looking for a solution but most answers seemed to work just by using separate(), any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please try strsplit using "fixed=TRUE". For example,  strsplit(as.character("Gbp4|AW228052|Mag-2|Mpa-2|Mpa2|-|5"),"|",fixed = T)

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a go! However if I'm to use that function for the entire column would I change it to strsplit(as.character(col name goes here),"|",fixed = T) ?

Comment: That's a case where trying it in your console would probably have been faster than waiting for an answer.  Also, it's usually recommended that you write out  TRUE instead of using T, which sometimes has unforeseen consequences.

Comment: Yup haha I didn't wait, I just wanted to make sure, so that ends up doing what I was looking for however the output is a list which I then have to convert into a dataframe, I was wondering if there was a way to do this where the new columns are just added onto my existing dataframe (like it would using the separate() function)

Comment: Please check "as.data.frame" function. Maybe also check "unlist". If you want to apply this operation to several columns in your df, please check sapply function.